# WARN [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] in system log what does that mean?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

i am seeing following warning in my system log

WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2016-08-27 09:13:34,110  AbstractCommitLogService.java:105 - Out of 24 commit log syncs over the past 240s with average duration of 3253.23ms, 2 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 91158.00ms

we are using following settings in yaml
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

does this mean my commit log is increasing in size so it couldn't sync in time ??

Answer (score 4):

It means that the commitlog could not be synced with the period specified in your YAML configuration. Wow, an average of 91 seconds... Twice... It could be something related to your disk IO (and these numbers could be there only if you have swap enabled on your system), or because you are experiencing very long GC pauses. Did you check the GC log files?

Comment: yes i checked GC most of them <200ms so i came to a conclusion problem is not with GC, probably have to start monitoring disk io wait times.

Comment: What's the CPU usage?